# Rasters with duplicated data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0, duplication

I am working with a number of raster files that suddenly appear to have duplicated records. For example, I have a raster that classifies my study area into aquatic (value = 1) and terrestrial (value = 0) habitats. Originally, the raster contained two rows: one for the terrestrial habitat, and one for the aquatic. Now, the file contains four rows: two for the terrestrial habitat and two for the aquatic. The duplicate records have the same cell count and encompass the exact same areas. This has happened to a number of files I am working with, with up to 18 duplicated records.

How could this have happened, and how do I fix it?

I am new to working with rasters.

I am working with ArcInfo 10.0, and it is the rows that are duplicated (please see screen shot).

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Rows or columns? Normally attributed rasters have columns for attributes but areas should not be duplicated in the record table (rows). What software are you using? Perhaps a screen shot would help explain what you're experiencing.

Comment: That is wierd. I notice the value and counts are identical so you should be able to remove the duplicates. Perhaps at some stage a copy/paste has been done inadvertently. The values in that table do not affect the raster but rather how the raster is seen; it's a special table but a table nonetheless and can be manipulated in the same way (add fields, append, copy/paste, delete rows...) which does not affect the pixels or their values in the raster.

Comment: Michael: good point. I did try to delete the rows, but I was unable to do so. Unfortunately, I am also unable to perform functions with the raster (e.g., use it in tools such as Extract by Mask and Raster Calculator). This has happened to multiple rasters within the MXD I am using (importing the affected rasters into another MXD did not help). Super weird. I exported the rasters to ASCII and then imported them back into GIS, which solves the problem for now. I would like to know why this happened so I can prevent it from happening again, but it seems like this will forever remain a mystery...